# Drag and Drop method for Android StaggeredGrid

Tags: android

Is it possible to make Drag and Drop method for Android `StaggeredGrid`?

I am using `PulseLauncherGrid` for drag and drop method but when I pass `StaggeredGridview` instead of gridview it throws `ClassCastException`.

Here is the code :

```
private StaggeredGridView grid;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        grid = (StaggeredGridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);

        if (getScreenOrientation() == 1)
            grid.setNumColumns(3);
        else
            grid.setNumColumns(4);

        items = new ArrayList<LauncherGridItem>();

        deleteZone = (DeleteZone) findViewById(R.id.delete_zone_view);
        dragLayer = (DragLayer) findViewById(R.id.drag_layer);

        adapter = new LauncherGridAdapter(this, items, grid, dragLayer,
                deleteZone);

        adapter.setPersistenceToken("MyLauncherGrid"); // optional, but if you

        adapter.setDragListener(this);
```

Comment: No, it's not that simple. You're confusing GridView which is an AdapterView (it recycles views) with GridLayout which is much simpler. Generally dragging and dropping grid items is a little bit complicated.

Comment: so i guess its possible to make drag and drap function for staggeredgridview but its kinda complicated.
also the SGV isnt normal gridview , instead its GridLayout.